# DNS config for server host and cloudflare

Tags: web-hosting, dns, cloudflare

Ok so I have my registrar, webhost and cloudflare, now my domain currently points to my host and I want to add cloudflare, and none of this is making sense because my host says they don't support cloudflare usage on their plans so they can't help me and my registrar says to point my domain to cloudflare and from cloudflare to my host. Does this make any sense to anyone??

Comment: No, it doesn't make any sense to me that companies are selling services but abandoning the user and forgetting that all this is still about computer science. Too many people rely on point-and-click availability of everything without understand the why and how. I do understand that the cost of hiring a computer science-type is expensive, and these service companies can't find enough of them themselves (and too many are the same point-and-clickers mentioned earlier) but often the reality: non-professionals/amateurs trying to piece together all this together without understanding most of it.

Comment: Note that I am not casting aspersions on you or anyone else. Sometimes, [a baby's gotta do what a baby's gotta do.](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=s71o6U7X3uI) ... :)

Answer (score 2):

If your webhost is unwilling to help you, since you pay them for a service, you should definitively go somewhere else.
In summary you would need at your registrar to specify cloudflare nameservers after setting things up with them, and provide Cloudflare details about your webhosting.

This may be tricky, especially if you already have some live services. So you should definitively work with a webhosting company that is willing to help you set things the way you want them to be.